# Using full code instead of shortcode

Tags: jwplayer

How do I use a full code for [JW Player plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/jw-player-plugin-for-wordpress/), not just the  shortcode?

I need it so that I can try and use the full code for Lightbox plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can embed the JW Player anywhere by just using the html embed code:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='/path/to/jwplayer.js'></script>

<div id='mediaspace'>This text will be replaced</div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
  jwplayer('mediaspace').setup({
    'flashplayer': 'player.swf',
    'file': 'http://content.longtailvideo.com/videos/flvplayer.flv',
    'controlbar': 'bottom',
    'width': '470',
    'height': '320'
  });
</script>
```

If you have options that you want to change, you can always use the [JW Wizard](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player-setup-wizard).

Comment: Changed my question to a coding one [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8480080/how-to-hide-video-before-a-thumbnail-image-is-clicked). Thanks for your help, you answer was a part of a solution to my actual problem and a complete answer to my question here.